# Youtube API frame not being loaded when document is ready?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, youtube-api

I am currently trying to trigger some functions, for when the embedded youtube player is being loaded, but for some reason is doesn't it seem like the API is being loaded, or the callback functions being triggered based on the API event states?

What am I doing wrong?

```
const $ = require('jquery');

$(document).ready( function() {
  console.log( "ready!" );
  loadPlayer();
});

function loadPlayer() { 
  if (typeof(YT) == 'undefined' || typeof(YT.Player) == 'undefined') {

    var tag = document.createElement('script');
    tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

    window.onYouTubePlayerAPIReady = function() {
      onYouTubePlayer();
    };

  } else {

    onYouTubePlayer();

  }
}

var player;

function onYouTubePlayer() {
  player = new YT.Player('player', {
    height: '490',
    width: '880',
    videoId: 'video',
    playerVars: { controls:1, showinfo: 0, rel: 0, showsearch: 0, iv_load_policy: 3 },
    events: {
      'onReady': window.onPlayerReadVar = function() {
        onPlayerStateChange();
      },
      'onStateChange': window.onPlayerStateChangeVar = function() {
        onPlayerStateChange();
      }
    }
  });
  console.log("youtubePlayerready")
}
  var done = false;

  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {

      console.log("onPlayerStateChange");
      done = true;
  }
```

When the page loads I only see "ready" outputted in the console.. Nothing else?

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `What am I doing wrong here?` You commented out two important lines.

Comment: These area already included in script tag

Comment: but can add for reproduciblity

Comment: is this nodejs? what framework do you use?

Comment: just jquery?  or?

Comment: @anita can you add your HTML code and the jquery reference? - check the console in your browser "press F12 key - (console) tab" and check whether you have errors. If so, please [edit] your question with the details of the error(s).

Comment: I just noticed that Tealium is already loading the Iframe, and have already defined the callback function for the defined states, which is why it not being called.  

Somehow I can have two running, and only trigger it for iframes with id = something?

Comment: that require function is not standard on web browser... what is it?

Comment: What is what?...